# Display PIL Image on Kivy Canvas

Tags: python, kivy, python-imaging-library

I can not find any documentation on how to display a PIL Image on a Kivy Canvas.

```
Rectangle(source=image) give TypeError: 'Image' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I need to use a pillow image due to other image manipulations. I even tried to load the image into a texture then apply the texture to the canvas but then I can't figure out how to convert the formats into something compatible. The Kivy documentation on how to load images on both textures and canvases is pretty much non-existent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.uix.image import Image as kiImage
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from io import BytesIO

canvas_img = Image.new('RGB', (240, 120), color=(255, 255, 255))
(do stuff to canvas_img)
data = BytesIO()
canvas_img.save(data, format='png')
data.seek(0) # yes you actually need this
im = CoreImage(BytesIO(data.read()), ext='png')
self.beeld = kiImage() # only use this line in first code instance
self.beeld.texture = im.texture
```

Comment: Ha, using BytesIO is exactly how I got around the problem. Its such a kludge though and makes some spectacular memory issues when you forget to seek(0) first.

Answer (score 5):

In the following example, it demonstrates using PIL Image to manipulate images and present it as *source*, *texture* and *canvas* of Kivy Image widgets.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.image import CoreImage
from kivy.lang import Builder

from PIL import Image

kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

<RootWidget>:
    img: img
    img3: img3
    img4: img4
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'PIL Image'

        Screen:
            RelativeLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img
                    pos_hint: {"left": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 1
                    allow_stretch: True

            RelativeLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img3
                    pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 1
                    allow_stretch: True

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'canvas'

        Screen:
            FloatLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img4
                    keep_data: True
                    allow_stretch: True
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1  # Black
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size


''')


class RootWidget(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        iw = Image.open("./DSC08518.JPG")   # Use PIL.Image
        iw.save('./phase.jpg')
        gray = iw.convert('1')
        gray.save('./gray_im.jpg')
        self.img.source = './phase.jpg'
        self.img3.texture = CoreImage('./gray_im.jpg').texture
        self.img4.source = './gray_im.jpg'


class KivyPILApp(App):
    title = "Kivy & PIL Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyPILApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Kivy Image Source & Texture]
[image: Img02 - Kivy Image canvas]

Comment: Good info but not quite what I had in mind. Can I load the image with PIL and then apply it as a texture property without saving and re-opening it with CoreImage? It seems awfully wasteful to save and reopen.