# kivy: how to show long images that exceed Texture max size

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on an app to show very long image the problem is that my Texture max size is <16384>, so i'm looking for a simple way to solved this, is there a way to expand my texture limit or maybe a way to segment the image into pieces.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you can expand the texture size limit. You can likely segment the image using something like `Pillow` or `opencv`, but even those will have some size limitations.

Comment: Any idea on how to segment and image on Pillow ?

Comment: Have not done it, but my first attempt would be to do `im = PIL.Image.open()`, then create smaller images using `im.crop()`. Another [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806100/display-pil-image-on-kivy-canvas) shows how to use the PIL image to create a Kivy Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly did it. I used John Anderson method to crop it with pillow im.crop().

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please comment one-line answers, thanks